# `service` no longer gives useful output (except with status) in 15.04?

Tags: server, services, 15.04

It used to be the case that

`service service-name reload|restart|start|stop` - would display a nice :

```
service-name start/running, process 17642
```

Now, while the new `status` output is really cool - I would really like to keep the old way - where it gives some kind of `[OK]` on `stop|start|restart|reload` - Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That's the output of `initctl start`, which is what `service` devolves to on upstart systems with upstart jobs.  The "new" output is the behaviour of `systemctl start` which is what `service` is devolving to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least,something like a script and an alias would probably do the trick, here...

Maybe:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# service-status
service "$1" "$2" 
if [[ $2 != "status ]]; then
    service "$1" status
fi
```

Or better yet; since `service` is really `systemctl` anyway:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# service-status 
systemctl "$2" "$1" 
if [[ $1 != "status" ]]; then 
    systemctl status "$1"
fi
```

and then add this to your `.bashrc` or your `.bash_aliases`:

```sh
alias service="service-status";
```

Comment: Better: use double quotes,  "$1" and "$2"

Comment: Where should this script be saved in 16.04?

Comment: You can put it anywhere your `$PATH` points to.  `/usr/local/bin` is probably a good spot. You'll want to save it as just "service-status" and don't forget to make it executable via `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/service-status` - or replace that path with whichever one you choose.

Comment: also tweaked it a bit

Answer (score 0):

My version of script, that gives me the result to the output:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
service "$1" "$2"
if [[ $2 != "status" ]]; then
    service --status-all | grep "$1"
fi
```