# How do I get service command to print output in 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, services

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10. In my 14.04 version the system give me return messages when I run `sudo service apache2 restart` or other service commands. But I not getting this returns in the new Ubuntu versions. Please see the picture, here I'm running the same command on the 14.04 and the 15.10 version, but only get return message on the 14.04 version. How to get those returns back on 15.10 version

[image]?

Answer (score 1):

## You're running the same command … but actually you're not.

You are using Ubuntu version 15.10, a systemd operating system.  Your system service management is no longer performed by upstart.  It is performed by systemd.

The `service` command may be the same … but the Debian/Ubuntu `service` command is a shell script that tries to auto-detect whether upstart or systemd is the running system service manager, and run the actual native service management commands for upstart and systemd.  It executes two pretty much entirely different code paths for upstart and for systemd.

upstart's native service management commands are `initctl start`, `initctl stop`, `initctl status` and so forth.  Those print messages as they go.

systemd's native service management commands are `systemctl start`, `systemctl stop`, `systemctl status` and so forth.  Those print no output as they operate.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233840/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/621209/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/613814/43344
- [`service` no longer gives useful output (except with status) in 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616906/)