# No output from service start/stop/restart command

Tags: command-line, 16.04, services, restart

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and found that when I run

```
usr@server:~$ sudo service <servicename> restart
usr@server:~$
```

The service is restarted (I can see the status with `service <servicename> status`), but the shell goes directly back to the command line without the expected:

```
* Stopping <servicename>     [ OK ]
* Starting <servicename>     [ OK ]
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the logs to see if there are any information that could help diagnose the problem? It should be in /var/log/

Comment: There is no problem with the service itself. It's the command prompt returning without output that baffles me.
It happens with every service. The command does what is expected (start/stop/restart the service), but there is no output

Answer (score 9):

## You should not be expecting such output.

For starters, Ubuntu didn't behave this way in earlier versions.  Ubuntu was an upstart system for just under a decade, and the behaviour of the `service` command on Ubuntu has for all those years not resembled what you are expecting.  One can see the upstart behaviour of the `service` command in the image in [How do I get service command to print output in 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713825/) .

The answer is pretty much the same for you as for the people with Ubuntu version 15.10 last year:

You are using Ubuntu version 16.10, a systemd operating system.  Your system service management is no longer performed by upstart (or whatever utility did it on whatever non-Ubuntu operating system you had before).  It is performed by systemd.

The `service` command may be the same … but the Debian/Ubuntu `service` command is a shell script that tries to auto-detect whether upstart or systemd is the running system service manager, and run the actual native service management commands for upstart and systemd.  It executes two pretty much entirely different code paths for upstart and for systemd.

upstart's native service management commands are `initctl start`, `initctl stop`, `initctl status` and so forth.  Those print messages as they go.

systemd's native service management commands are `systemctl start`, `systemctl stop`, `systemctl status` and so forth.  Those print no output as they operate.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233840/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/621209/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/613814/43344
- [`service` no longer gives useful output (except with status) in 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616906/)

Comment: "You should not be expecting such output." is not a great place to start an answer. You're basically saying, "Your opinion is wrong". What you meant to say, I think, is "this is not possible with systemd".

During the upstart days, Ubuntu DID output... it's in the question for "How do I get service command to print output in 15.10". Prior to 15.10, Ubuntu used upstart and upstart (like sysvinit) was verbose. So please don't say, "It's been like this for a decade". It hasn't. It changed in 15.10. Systemd is not verbose and that's been super irritating ever since distros started deploying it.

Comment: The questioner quite clearly told you what xe was expecting, and the upstart output does not resemble that.  You are confused, or did not read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need an OK output. No output means OK. When a service doesn't start properly Ubuntu show you something like this:

> Job for php5.6-fpm.service failed because the control process exited
>   with error code. See "systemctl status php5.6-fpm.service" and
>   "journalctl -xe" for details.

In my case this example was a misconfiguration on my php-fpm.conf that unabling the service to start. After follow the instructions I sorted what was causing the error.