# Making systemd service unit produce output on start/stop

Tags: 16.04, services, systemd

I have added a service unit in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
[Unit]
Description=seaweedfs
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/root/work/bin/weed -v=0 volume -mserver=18.21.1.150:9333 -ip=8.9.4.9 -dir=/storage -max=2270 -images.fix.orientation=false -pulseSeconds=1
```

Everything is working fine. But I want to know if the process has been started or not. Or if it stopped, then I want to see some output as it has been stopped.

Right now am doing `service seaweedfs start`. It starts but doesn't show any message. I want to add some useful messages to it on start or stop.

Will be thankful for any help :)

Comment: What about `systemctl start seaweedfs`?

Comment: Sorry I didnt  get? This is what i have asked. I have asked how can I add some information about start and stop in file?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry. Usually, you don't, since `systemd` will swallow any and all output from starting a unit and send it to the logs. You will probably have to write a wrapper around `service` (or call `service seaweedfs status` immediately after).

Comment: Yeah tahnks.. But couldn't it be a post and pre script type thing? to echo something if it started or not?

Comment: There are the `ExecStartPost` and `ExecStopPost` options, but as I said, the output will go to the logs.

Comment: Okay thanks,, Can you tell how can i used these things in service unit
`start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
limit nofile 1000000 1000000`

Comment: This duplicates http://askubuntu.com/questions/792940/

Answer (score 0):

You can check `sudo netstat -nlutp | grep weed` to see if the port assigned in your .service file, (9333 in this case) opened.

If you see like this, the service may started

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:8081        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25878/./weed
tcp6       0      0 :::9333                 :::*                    LISTEN      1244/./weed
```